# RIFT Power Nodes

Tags: rift

*In the game RIFT, what are Power Nodes used for, such as:*

**Faint Empyreal Power Node
Empyreal Shoulder Power Node
Empyreal Chest Armour Power Node**

Answer (score 1):

They are used to upgrade good that are purchased from the adventure dealer.

You can check out the [item list here](https://rift.magelo.com/en/items?q=power%20node) and search for power nodes like I did.